# How to make slideshow images 100% width and height of browser

Tags: css, image, fluid-layout

I have scoured relative questions on here and it seems like my situation is slightly unique.

I have a jQuery slideshow that I am wanting to make `100%` width and height of browser with pure CSS.

I am able to get the width `100%` and have it stretch with the page via my fluid layout, however when I try to make the height `100%` it the image goes away completely.

It is forcing me to define the height with pixels.

I'm going to have a footer and header that stretch `100%` width over the image / background with a wrapper inside each that is `960px` wide.

**Here is HTML structure:**

```
<div class="page-section header clear">

        <div class="wrapper clear">
            <div class="logo clear">

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

<div class="page-section clear">
<!-- 100% width -->

        <div id="revolver">
            <div class="revolver-slide"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/slides/slide-2.jpg"></div>
            <div class="revolver-slide"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/slides/slide-1.jpg"></div>
            <div class="revolver-slide"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/slides/slide-2.jpg"></div>
            <div class="revolver-slide"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/slides/slide-1.jpg"></div>

        </div>


</div>
    <div class="footer page-section clear">


                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="footer_nav clear">
                            <div class="footer_nav_text">
                                SERIES
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
```

**Here is the CSS:**

```
body {
 min-height:100%;
}
img. {
 max-width:100%;
}
.page-section {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0px auto 0px auto;
}
.wrapper {
 width:960px;
 margin:0px auto 0px auto;
 padding:0px 20px 0px 20px; 
}
/* header */
.header {
 height:27px;
 background-color:#fff;
 position:absolute; top:20px; 
 z-index:100001;
}
#revolver {
 background-color:#ccc;
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:100%;
 z-index:10001;
}

.revolver-slide {
 background-color:#fff;
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:100%;
 background-position:center center;
 -webkit-background-size:cover;
 -moz-background-size:cover;
 -o-background-size:cover;
 background-size:cover;
}
.footer {
     height:25px;
     background-color:#fff;
     z-index:1000001;
     position:relative;
     margin-bottom:15px;
     border:1px #000 solid;
}
```

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: ``max-height`` and ``max-width`` are only a constraints; they don't set the elements' sizes. Use ``width`` and ``height`` instead, and I think it should work.

Comment: you need to target the image inside the div and use min-height if you want to stretch it all the way. See if this helps  .revolver-slide img {
 width:100%;
 min-height:100%;

}

Comment: @afEkenholm I'm afraid that didn't work

Comment: @Chou One that didnt' work either, it was close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this? I have put

```
    html,body
    {height:100%;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p4z8q/14/